# How to output to console a bool?

Tags: c#

I want a concise way to output a bool? in c#. Currently, I am doing this which is very bulky.

```
string outputString = boolValNullable.HasValue && boolValNullable.Value ? "true" : "false";
```

I want to do something like:

```
string outputString = boolValNullable ?? "null"
```

The above is invalid syntax.

Comment: One option `string outputString = $"{boolValNullable.GetValueOrDefault()}";`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ it returns `False` when `boolValNullable` is `null`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I know it does... bool is `false` by default. That's what that does.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ But OP wants to return `"null"` string in this case

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski Well, OP need's to make their mind up, first code block clashes with second, pick your poison right? Either the OP want's `true` or `false` and or `null` included as well, but not defined clearly; it would help if we *knew* how this was going to be used...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
string output = boolValNullable?.ToString() ?? "null"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you. Pass in your bool to this method and it will output to your console.

```
public void OutputBoolToConsole(bool? myBool)
{
    var myBoolAsString = myBool?.ToString() ?? "bool is null";
    Console.WriteLine(myBoolAsString);
}
```

Comment: bool and nullable bool are not the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use a [conditional operator `?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for that

```cs
string outputString = boolValNullable.HasValue ? boolValNullable.Value.ToString() : "null";
```

or simply use [`Nullable<T>.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method, if you want to get an empty string in case of `boolValNullable` equals `null`

```cs
string outputString = boolValNullable.ToString();
```

It returns

> The text representation of the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object
>   if the `HasValue` property is `true`, or an empty string ("") if the
>   `HasValue` property is `false`.

[`Boolean.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method returns either `True` of `False` (the first letter is capital). If you need a lower case, you should add `ToLower()` call after `ToString()`